# Calculate $g^2, g^3, f^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Everyone. I am not sure how to start this problem. If anyone can show me a step by step process with an explanation I would appreciate it.

If $S= \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$, let $f,g\in S_4$ be defined by:
$$f:x_1\to x_2, x_2\to x_3, x_3\to x_4, x_4\to x_1$$
and:
$$g:x_1\to x_2, x_2\to x_1, x_3\to x_3, x_4\to x_4$$

Comment: Hint: If $f$ sends $x_1\to x_2$ and $x_2 \to x_3$ then $f^2$ sends $x_1$ to $x_3$.

Comment: Just follow the arrows...

Comment: @DerekAllums thanks for the hint! I understand know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f(x)$:

- $f(x_1)=x_2$
- $f(x_2)=x_3$
- $f(x_3)=x_4$
- $f(x_4)=x_1$

Compute $f^2(x)$ as follows:

- $f^2(x_1)=f(f(x_1))=f(x_2)=x_3$
- $f^2(x_2)=f(f(x_2))=f(x_3)=x_4$
- $f^2(x_3)=f(f(x_3))=f(x_4)=x_1$
- $f^2(x_4)=f(f(x_4))=f(x_1)=x_2$

You can use this example in order to compute $g^2(x)$ and $g^3(x)$...

Comment: this question is assumin that x1 x2 .. are separate elements and not subsets. Am I right @barak manos

Comment: @DSinghvi: Subsets of what?

Comment: means subsets of any thing let say real numbers. what I wanted to say is they are discrete elements and since we x1 -> x2 can mean if x1 contain  elements that each elemet would have its different image in x2

Comment: @barakmanos thanks! Very helpful! I understand what I am doing know.

Comment: @StevenLynn: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

It's customary to use this notation

$$g=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}=(12)\leftarrow\text{transposition}$$
so
$$g^2=\operatorname{id}\quad;\quad g^3=g$$
and by the same method we have
$$f=(1234)\leftarrow\text{cycle}$$
so
$$f^2=(13)(24)$$

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication on $S_{n}$ is defined as function composition
thus 
$$
f^{2}(x)=f(f(x)),g^{3}(x)=g(g(g(x)))
$$

etc'

Just evaluate the above terms at $x_{i}$ with $1\leq i\leq4$ to
determine what permutations of $S_{4}$ they are